# Make Hebrew text/plain email right-justified

Tags: email, smtp, hebrew

I am writing a script for Unity and I have a problem. I want to do the newsletter for a couple of people. I am using System.Mail. Here is my C# code:

```
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress(e_mail);
    mail.To.Add(email);
    mail.Subject = "ברוכים הבאים לאלמינדה‎";
    mail.Body =
    "!ברוכים הבאים לאלמינדה \n" +
    ".תודה על הרשמתכם \n" +
    "www.elminda.com :לקבלת מידע נוסף ולצפייה בסרטון קצר המתאר את הטכנולוגיה של אלמינדה, בקרו באתר שלנו";


    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(e_mail, password) as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
```

But since the language is Hebrew, I expect that the location of the sentences will be on the right, but it will be on the left. How to do so
what would it be on the right? (The option with spaces is not suitable, since it all depends on the different screen resolutions and on the mobile phone it all breaks down)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the text in reverse order to get it to display right-to-left, begin your message with a Unicode RTL mark [U+200F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) and put the rest of the text in the order you would write it (I can't read Hebrew but from your description I guess starting with יכורב...)

Comment: Thank. But it still does not transfer the text to the right side of the field on gmail. As I understand it, your advice helps to turn the text in the opposite direction without any extra effort. But how to display it on the right side of fields?
Here is an example of how it should look like:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/4cc95eb707430a6014f1405c27523fad/1540042400/59769/1276656/right_side.jpg

Comment: I don't think I understand what the image is supposed to illustrate. Your text is now right-aligned; correct?

Comment: `print("\u200f")`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I added to the beginning of each line:

 "\u200f !ברוכים הבאים לאלמינדה \n" +
 "\u200f .תודה על הרשמתכם \n" +
 "\u200f www.elminda.com :לקבלת מידע נוסף ולצפייה בסרטון קצר המתאר את הטכנולוגיה של אלמינדה, בקרו באתר שלנו";

but all the text still remains on the left side of the message:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/0b383bb7d85b32fdb9b1f04bca29cde9/1540053132/73944/1276656/leftSide.jpg